# What use is a test set in a continuous training setting?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling, hyperparameter

I have tuned and trained a model that predicts an aspect of customer behavior from behavior within the most recent 12 months. After initial training, generalization performance was estimated based on a held out test set. The train/test split was done on customers, not individual examples (each customer may contribute multiple examples overall).

Once in production, I would like to re-train the model periodically to take into account new data, say every month. Hyperparameters are retained from the initial model. The updated data set will be obtained from a one-year sliding window. Hence, on the second training occasion, 11 months in the data set will be the same as during initial training and the rest will be new data from the most recent month, which may include examples from new customers.

Now, if I want to estimate generalization performance each time I re-train the model, then of course the new test set must not contain examples that were in the training set for initial model building, since hyperparameters have been optimized to do well on these examples. This means I have to re-use my original train/test split forever, each month enriching either set with new customers and dropping from either set past customers who do not fall into the one year window anymore. (Note that number of new customers per time is too low and the time scale of relevant customer behavior is too large to create a useful test set from new customers only)

**The issue I see is that I will never be allowed to make any decision based on the test performance of re-trained models**, since this would essentially be equivalent to over time fitting the model on the test set as long as I do not start tabula rasa. For instance, say I use the test set performance as a signal to do some hyperparameter tuning, starting from the current parameters. Then even if the tuning is done using cross validation on the training set, the fact alone that the decision to do some tuning was based on the test set means I am adjusting my model to do better on *that* particular test set.

**In other words, no information obtained since the initial model build must be used to construct a new model, or the test set will be overfit over time. So the only permittable use I see for a test set is to trigger a completely new model search process, starting from random hyperparameters or from exactly the same vantage point as during initial training.**

**Assuming the above reasoning is sound, my question is what common practices are used in MLOps in such a situation.** Is test set performance commonly used at all anymore, or does the close monitoring of production performance take its place? What could be considered best practice? (Though I feel it may depend heavily on area and severity of consequences)

Thanks in advance!

*Edit: I feel the question is in fact more generally applicable. How useful is a test set if the only thing it can tell us is whether we should throw our model in the garbage to start over with new, independent data, which is often practically impossible to obtain?*

*Edit 2: [Very similar question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49612/whats-the-point-of-the-test-set), phrased a little more succinctly.*

Comment: You might be interested in a rolling forecast and [time series cross-validation](https://medium.com/@soumyachess1496/cross-validation-in-time-series-566ae4981ce4). One use is to consider each new observation as a "true" value to compare your model trained with everything up until then with.

Comment: Thanks, very good point, this is probably best practice. The reason I chose to not split on time is that we're dealing with a very imbalanced classification problem (the splits are in fact stratified). To have enough examples of the minority class in the test set, the "future" time period from which we would pick test cases would have to be quite extensive, so extensive that it would be larger than the re-training period and include major portions of a customer's lifetime. So in the end we would gradually arrive at a situation similar to splitting on customers. Or am I overlooking something?